# How to know which file holds grep result?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

There is a directory which contains 100 text files. I used grep to search a given text in the directory as follow:

```
cat *.txt | grep Ya_Mahdi
```

and grep shows `Ya_Mahdi`.

I need to know which file holds the text. Is it possible?

Comment: What does `man grep` tell you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get rid of `cat` and provide the list of files to `grep`:

```
grep Ya_Mahdi *.txt
```

While this would generally work, depending on the number of `.txt` files in that folder, the argument list for grep might get too large.

You can use `find` for a bullet proof solution:

```
find --maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -exec grep -H Ya_Mahdi {} +
```

Comment: That would not print the filename.

Comment: @hek2mgl That depends on the version of grep the OP is using. I'm running Mac OS X, and the built-in grep (grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD) prints the filename if multiple filenames are provided as input. The only case where it doesn't is if you provide only a *single* file as input. Are you sure you tested it with more than one file matching *.txt ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does not depend on the grep version. The problem is that you have your `GREP_OPTIONS` variable set and it contains `-H` - or `grep` is an alias in your shell. (Try /bin/grep in the latter case)

Comment: @hek2mgl I don't have `GREP_OPTIONS` set. In fact, I just tested it on an Ubuntu 15.04 VM (GNU grep 2.20), and this also prints the filename if there's more than one file matching the *.txt pattern.

Comment: Try `/bin/grep` on Ubuntu

Comment: Uh, I need to correct myself. The man page says: `-H  Print the file name for each match.  This is  the  default  when
              there is more than one file to search.`. You are right! :)

Comment: @hek2mgl Glad we agree :-)
But using `-H` is certainly more robust, since it will also print the filename if there's only one file matching the pattern.

Comment: I felt so free and added the find part of my answer to yours. I hope that is ok.